# How to create PDF Report with data from code in list form, not directly from database with Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, rdlc, reportviewer

I am using Microsoft.Report.Viewer for generate PDF in my ASP .NET WEB API application. So far when my report get the data directly from database, there is no problem. The problem is, when I try to create a report with subreport within and the subreport data is got from code in a list form, I didn't get the expected result. What I do is create a report with subreport from this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473844/Using-Custom-Data-Source-to-create-RDLC-Reports). But when I generate the PDF, what I get is this message [image: message].

Here is my code :

My Web API to generate the PDF :

```
[Route("GeneratePDFForDailyProgram")]
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GeneratePDFForDailyProgram(int id) {

        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string fileName = string.Concat("Booking_No" + Convert.ToString(id) + "_" + guid.ToUpper() + ".pdf");
        string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Temp/" + fileName);
        string name = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CUSTOMPORT"]];
        string name2 = Request.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot;
        List<TourDestination> destination = new List<TourDestination>();

        TourTransactionSummaryViewModel summaryViewModel = new TourTransactionSummaryViewModel();

        try {

            //summaryViewModel = await CalcSummaryViewModel(transaction, summaryViewModel, db);

            summaryViewModel.DailyPrograms = DailyProgram(id);
            destination = TourDestination(summaryViewModel.DailyPrograms);

            List < Movement > movementList = summaryViewModel.DailyPrograms.FirstOrDefault().Movements.ToList();
            Reports.ReportGenerator.GeneratePDFForDailyProgram(summaryViewModel.DailyPrograms, destination, filePath);
            //await Reports.ReportGenerator.GeneratePDFForMovement(movementList,  filePath);


            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;

            result.Dispose();

            string convertedFilePath = filePath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");



        } catch (Exception ex) {

            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }

        return Ok(name + name2 + "/Content/Temp/" + fileName);
    }
```

As you can see from the code above, I use GeneratePDFForDailyProgram method to generate the PDF.

Here my GeneratePDFForDailyProgram method :

```
public static bool GeneratePDFForDailyProgram(TourTransactionSummaryViewModel.DailyProgram[] dailyPrograms, List<TourDestination> destination , string filePath) {

        try {
            string binPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(binPath + "\\TripPlannerAPI.dll"));

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(DailyProgramReport)) {
                var viewer = new ReportViewer();
                viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
                viewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);

                Warning[] warnings;
                string[] streamids;
                string mimeType;
                string encoding;
                string filenameExtension;

                viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);
                viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DailyProgram", dailyPrograms));


                byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render(
                    "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
                    out streamids, out warnings);

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)) {
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    fs.Flush();
                }

                stream.Flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

To run the SubReport, I use the eventhandler code :

```
private static void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e) {

        DateTime movementDate = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Parameters[0].Values[0]);

        TourTransactionsController controller = new TourTransactionsController();

        var movement = controller.Movements();


        List<Movement> movementList = new List<Movement>();
        movementList.Add(new Movement {
            Destination = "TEST",
            MovementDescription = "TEST",
            DateTime =  Convert.ToDateTime("2017-09-25") //HARDCODE FOR TEST
        });

        e.DataSources.Clear();

        e.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource() {
            Name = "DSMovements",
            Value = movementList
        });

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

What I did try :

1. Check the sub report name, and change it from report name to report file url. Still get the same message.
2. Generate the Sub Report directly, not from the main report. The subreport is successfully generated.

PS : When I debug my code, and put a breakpoint in my event handler `LocalReport_SubreportProcessing` the breakpoint is not hitting while debugging

My Questions are :

1. Why my breakpoint on the eventhandler is not hitting while debugging ?
2. Is it possible that eventhandler  which is not hitting while debugging, could be the reason I got the message `The subreport 'MovementReport' could not be
   found at the specified location MovementReport.
   Please verify that the subreport has been
   published and that the name is correct.` ?
3. Is there any other way for me to create a main report with data from db, and the subreport with data from code in list form ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it just cannot find rdlc file - check your subreport properties to make sure that the name is correct.

Comment: I already checked it more than one time, and I'm pretty sure that the name is correct.